# Unique Columns Across an Array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique

I have an array structured like so:

```
a = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5;
     1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3];
```

Pretty much, it's a 2 by n (I simplified my matrix in this question with reduced number of columns for simplicity's sake), no real pattern. I want to be able to **find the unique number of columns**. So in this simplified example, I can (but it'll take a while) count by hand and noticed that my unique matrix b is:

```
b=  1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 
    1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3
```

In MATLAB, I can do something like

```
size(b,2)
```

To get the number of unique columns. In this example

```
size(b,2) = 12
```

My question is, how do I go from matrix a to matrix b so that I can do this computationally for very large n dimensional matrices that I have?

Comment: It seems you want the number of unique _columns_, not _permutations_. If that's the case, you should change the title and the wording to reflect that

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you for the suggestion, I changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
a = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5;
    1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3];

% Transpose to leverage the rows flag, then transpose back
b = unique(a.', 'rows').';
```

Which returns:

```
b =

     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     4     5     5
     1     2     1     2     3     1     2     3     4     1     2     3
```

Comment: Damn was about to click the "Post" button. However, isn't there an option on unique to directly be used on the columns rather than the rows? I've been searching but didn't find out

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior no, hence this solution. There are other options should the data size make two transpose calls time prohibitive.

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior see [this MATLAB central post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/157617) for discussion of other options.